# Creating a list of a class that has a list of a class inside it in python

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create 3 different teams with 3 different players on each team. But right now all the players on each team are the same. Below is the code I have. If anyone has a solution that would be great.

```
class player():
    name=''

class team():
    name=''
    players=[]

teams=[]

for i in range (3):
    teams.append(team())
    teams[i].name=str(i)
    for j in range(3):
        teams[i].players.append(player())
        teams[i].players[j].name='P'+str(i)+str(j)
```

Comment: Do you want each instance of the player class to have a different name, or one name for all of the players? I think a [tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just assign a value to an attribute of the class in the root definition. This will set the attribute for all instances of the class. Use the constructor (`__init__()` method) to assign values to attributes and then change them:

```
    class player():
        def __init__(self):
            self.name=''

    class team():
        def __init__(self):
            self.name=''
            self.players=[]
```

This way each player and each team gets its own `name` attribute and each team their own list of players.

You can also accept arguments in the `__init__()` method to name the team and player directly:

```
    class player():
        def __init__(self,playername=''):
            self.name=playername

    p = player("Jim")
```

This will initiate a player who already has the `.name` attribute set to "Jim".

Comment: Wouldn't you include `name` in the initializer?

Comment: I personally would, yes. I'm notorious for long parameter lists in initializers. But that's a matter of taste, I think.

Comment: It's also worth including `players` as a parameter to `team.__init__()`. OP could then get the user code down to a single line if they wanted: `teams = [team(str(i), [player(f'P{i}{j}' for j in range(3)]) for i in range(3)]`

Comment: Possible. But I don't think OP worries too much about code golf at this moment.